# How to calculate max nos. of threads that can be created based on system specification using python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm creating a multithreaded application using "Python". I want to know how many maximum numbers of thread can be created.

Theoretically, we can create as many threads as we want but practically it is based on the system specification.

So what is the formula to calculate the no of threads according to the system?

Comment: There is no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Total No of threads does not depend on the system specification**

No of `threads` in `Running` state does.

Comment: If I create as many threads I want, it may cause system blocking call. So how to avoid this scenario ?

Comment: you should create only as much as you need

Comment: This statement already said by the OP. How this become as a solution ?